# how to remove Breakpoint "bar" in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Don't know if this bar has always been here, I have been messing around with some settings in Eclipse and I do not remember having this bar.

How do I remove this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Preferences-> General-> Text Editors`, disable `Show range indicator`.